# What is 'NodeJS' module in Node.js? (asking because it's so hard to google it)

Tags: node.js

I was searching where nodejs `global` object comes from, and found that `global` object actually comes from a module called... `NodeJS`. What exactly is this module? Perhaps the objects in this module are auto-imported to the global context? Is there any document about this?

The problem is that, because of its name `NodeJS`, it is so hard to google it to find where this is documented.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html

Comment: @Michael I think the page explains the objects in global scope, but not exactly about `NodeJS` module.

Comment: it literally is nodejs. u can use npm to update it by downloading nodejs to global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no NodeJS module in node, I think that you are refering to typescript namescpase from typings https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/globals.d.ts#L144

`declare var global: NodeJS.Global;`

`global` object is set on `Global context` during Node.js environment initialization, starting probably from this point https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/api/environment.cc#L446

During node.js debugging we can see that during running script `loaders.js` https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/bootstrap/loaders.js

there is no `global` object on Global scope

[image]

But during running thru node.js script https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/bootstrap/node.js the `global` object is in place

[image]

Comment: Indeed I was using typescript. Your answer is exactly what I wanted to know.